# Reverse for '' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: []

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

I created a Bid Class in my Django model. When i am trying to get bid_list it is returning 
"NoReverseMatch at /bid_list/
Reverse for 'accept_bid' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'user': }' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['accept_bid/(?P\d+)/$', '/$']"

Here's my code:

models.py:

```
class Bid(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True)
    amount = models.IntegerField()


def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("accept_bid", kwargs={"user": self.user})

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.amount
```

views.py:

```
queryset = Bid.objects.all().order_by('amount')
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^bid_list/$', views.bid_list, name='bid_list'),
url(r'^accept_bid/(?P<user>\d+)/$', views.accept_bid, name='accept_bid'),
```

bid_list.html:

```
{% for bid in queryset %}
<tbody>
<tr> 
<td>{{bid.user}}</td>  

<td>{{bid.amount}}</td> 

<td>
<input type='submit'  href='{{ bid.get_absolute_url }}' value='Accept' /></td>

</tr> 

</tbody>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've allowed the user field to be None, but you're relying on it in the get_absolute_url method. Since it's blank, the lookup fails.

It seems a bit strange for the URL for a Bid to depend on the user id but not the bid id. You probably want to use `self.id` there.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer. I couldn't able to get bid.get_absolute_url in <input type=submit> How can i do this?

Comment: Not quite sure what you are doing. Inputs don't have hrefs; what happens when you submit a form is controlled by the form element itself, in the `action` attribute.